# Filtering data in magento REST API

Tags: magento2, filter, rest-api, http-request, search-criteria

I use this API to fetch the visible products using the filter:

http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%Nike%&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like

Is there a better way to search from the REST API ? This URL will become really big in case of increased search terms, for instance, If I query for 10 SKU names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to use search API (`rest/V1/search`), is faster because based on index tables, and then load full information about products returned from search using product repository (`rest/V1/products`).

You would have a list of product IDs returned by search API and `in` filter can be used when creating search criteria for `rest/V1/products`, this will make URL shorter. However, request URL for Search API would still be long.

There is no way to reduce URL length except for introducing alternative `POST` or `PUT` endpoing in your module (`VendorName/ModuleName/etc/webapi.xml`). Then you should be able to specify filters in request body.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/searchProducts" method="POST">
        <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Comment: can you help out with the modification in webapi.xml.. any tutorial link ?

Comment: Take a look at official docs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0//extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html

Comment: Ok.. and also the http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria is giving error. I think, the search criteria parameter should be same across all the requests, but it is giving an error.

Comment: Field name should be `search_term`, see php example here http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90607/697 , also try to check out documentation for search API on Magento dev docs

Comment: http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][searchTerm]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%Nike%&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like. this still gives error

Comment: Also tried this one: http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][search_term]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%Nike%&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like

Comment: please throw some light on search_term parameter..

Comment: Take a look at implementation in `\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection::_renderFiltersBefore` and usage in test `\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchTest::testCatalogSearch`