# Add a custom filter to search in magento2

Tags: magento2, search, filter, magento-2.0

I'm new with Magento2, I have a problem trying to add a new filter to the search module.

For example:

I created an attribute that names: "flag" of type "text field", that will be invisible in storefront.

I have 3 products:

### name     |   description  | flag

Product1 |  Description1  |  1

Product2 |  Description2  |  1

Product3 |  Description3  |  0

When I type in the search box "product", by default Magento2 returns all the products, because all matches with the
search, what I want is add a filter to the search, that only returns the products with flag = 1, so it will returns only the product 1 and 2.

I don't know what is the exactly block or model that I must override.

Comment: Look at this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90209/magento2-advanced-searching-smartsearch/90607#90607

Comment: @darkangelo, are you asking about the catalog product grid?

Comment: Hi Arkadii, I saw the link in your comment, but that's only work for the autocomplete search, which is good, but I need to do the same when you click on the search button

Answer (score 3):

Look for the grid's listing page like [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-filter.html). The product listing for regular catalog can be found [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml) (it differs for configurable product etc). For your custom attribute's config, add

`<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>`

and the filter should show up on the header for that field.

Comment: Thanks Maddy for your answer, what I need is modify the search in frontend, the link that you gave me is for the admin

Comment: Sorry I was confused about what exactly you needed.